# laravel eager loading with "with"

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Place extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('place', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('place', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

this is my model

and here in my controller I try to make a load with "with", but after I call the `get()` method, I get an error:

```
Class 'place' not found
```

this is how I do it:

```
    $data['places'] = Place::with('children', 'parent')->get();
```

the class Itself is there, but this happens only if I call the `get()` or `find()` methods
any clues?

Comment: Place::with(['children', 'parent'])->get(); change it like this

Comment: tryed like this "Place::with(['children', 'parent'])->get();" still same error

Comment: Check My answer I have update the model code also

Comment: Place::get() has error or not?

Answer (score 1):

Change it like this, as in you need to mention the namespace and model,
In both function 'App\Place'

```
public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Place', 'parent_id');
}

Place::with(['children', 'parent'])->get();
OR
Place::with('children')->with('parent')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your relationships are wrong,  use `App\Place` note `App` and capital `P` in place.

```
class Place extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Place', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Place', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```